# How does one do async ajax calls using cherrypy?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, asynchronous, cherrypy

I'm using cherrypy's standalone server (cherrypy.quickstart()) and sqlite3 for a database.

I was wondering how one would do ajax/jquery asynchronous calls to the database while using cherrypy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would do them using any other webserver - by getting your javascript to call a URL which is handled by the server-side application.

Comment: Yup. CherryPy doesn't care how you call it as long as it's HTTP. From the server side, AJAX looks just like any other request. You might have to set cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] to 'application/json' or whatever you are returning...

Answer (score 9):

If you are using CherryPy [3.2.0-rc1](http://www.cherrypy.org/browser/tags/cherrypy-3.2.0rc1) then you can use the decorators `@json_in` and `@json_out` ([see here](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/WhatsNewIn32#Tools)).

Thus:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@tools.json_in(on = True)
@tools.json_out(on = True)
def json_test(self):
    return { 'message':'Hello, world!' }
```

will return JSON to the browser, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('/json_test', function(data) {
        alert(data.message);
    }
}
```

You need to remember that CherryPy expects JSON posts to have a content type of `application/json`, to do that with jQuery, either use `$.ajax` and manaully set `contentType` or you can use the following convenience function:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    $.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset:"utf-8", 
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8" });
    $.post(url, $.toJSON(data), callback, "json");
}
```

This function uses the [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) plugin, but you could use a different method to convert to JSON.

Comment: What about imports? `from cherrypi import tools`?